# How to specify column names through parameter in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
USE Database
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE FillTable
    @Id nvarchar(50), 
    @ColumnNameArray nvarchar(4000),
    @ColumnValueArray nvarchar(4000)
AS 
   INSERT INTO Table(@ColumnNameArray)
   VALUES (@ColumnValueArray)    
GO
```

This is the functionality i require in my stored procedure. But i get the error as

`Invalid column name '@zoneNameArray'.`

So whats the work around?

How can I make this work?

**EDIT 1:** 
I tried using it like this as said by SO users.

```
select @sql_Str='
      INSERT INTO Table('+@ColumnNameArray+')
       VALUES ('+@ColumnValueArray+')'
```

But i still have error. The `ColumnNameArray` goes well. But wen it comes to `ColumnValueArray` i still cant get it right. 
`ColumnValueArray` consists of both `strings` and `int`.
eg: `ColumnValueArray = "12,'abc','dddd',45,'2333'"` this is what i pass from my front end (C#) to the stored procedure parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this

```
   declare @sql_Str varchar(8000)
    select @sql_Str='
      INSERT INTO Table('+@ColumnNameArray+')
       VALUES ('+@ColumnValueArray+')'
    exec(  @sql_Str);
```

Assuming @ColumnNameArray is a comma separated list of columns

Comment: @Rohit: Definitely, please let me know if you face any problem

Comment: yeah i do. Can you pls add up code for making comma separated string from string array?

Comment: @Rohit: string array means , are you storing it in a table?.. what is your input to your stored procedure FillTable ?

Comment: i have `string columnNames[]` and `string columnValues[]`

Comment: @Rohit: I think you are using a front end application to call this procedure.  you have to make the column separated string in the front end code and then pass that value to the procedure.

Comment: But i Have trouble with inserting strings as column values.

Comment: Could you please explain me more , how you are trying?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
exec('INSERT INTO Table(' + @ColumnNameArray + ') VALUES (' + @ColumnValueArra + ')')
```

### edit

wrap a stored procedure around it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FillTable
    @Id nvarchar(50), 
    @ColumnNameArray nvarchar(4000),
    @ColumnValueArray nvarchar(4000)
AS 
    exec('INSERT INTO Table(' + @ColumnNameArray + ') VALUES (' + @ColumnValueArra + ')')
GO
```

Comment: Not in exec! i need a real stored procedure. :(

Comment: But i Have trouble with inserting strings as column values.

Comment: You can escape the string delimiter `'` with double `'` or `\'`: `'INSERT INTO Table(' + @ColumnNameArray + ') VALUES (\'' + @ColumnValueArra + '\')'`

Comment: It becomes `INSERT INTO ''column1','column2','column3'' VALUES (''value1','value2','value3'')`